# Получение свойства из JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Я работаю с API в js.
API возвращает - `[{"id":134568,"username":"xtrafrancyz","level":20,"rank":"ADMIN","playedSeconds":4111133}]`

Как мне через js получить свойство, например `username`?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [{"id":134568,"username":"xtrafrancyz","level":20,"rank":"ADMIN","playedSeconds":4111133}];

console.log(data[0].username);
```

Comment: Cпасибо тебе  :3

Comment: Почему код без пояснений? И почему ничего не рассказали про [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Answer (score 0):

Для разбора данных в формате JSON в JavaScript предусмотрен специальный метод [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Его преимущество над простой интерпретацией текста с помощью [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) заключается в невозможности выполнения произвольного кода. Это может быть полезно, если данные приходят из недоверенного источника или по сети, где их может скомпроментировать злоумышленник.

Кроме того, у вас остаётся возможность заменять исходные данные, не модифицируя код программы.

```js
var str = '[{"id":134568,"username":"xtrafrancyz","level":20,"rank":"ADMIN","playedSeconds":4111133}]'

var arr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(arr[0].username);
```